# How to add migration in .NET Core Library project in web API core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, .net-core, dbcontext, entity-framework-migrations

I am new in .net core. I am adding migration in .net core Liabrary project in web API core 1.1. using below code.

```
Add-Migration example1
```

But it's showing below error:[image]

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using VS Code or other editor:**

In dotnet command cli type:
**dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate**

obs:InitialCreate  is the name of migration, you can give any name.

**If you are using Visual Studio:**
Create your database
Once you have a model, you can use migrations to create a database.
Open the PMC:
Tools –> NuGet Package Manager –> Package Manager Console
Run **Add-Migration InitialCreate** to scaffold a migration to create the initial set of tables for your model.
  **If you receive an error starting The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, close and reopen Visual Studio.** 
Run Update-Database to apply the new migration to the database. This command creates the database before applying migrations.

**Source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db

Comment: If using `dotnet ef` with VS Code, some good setup instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet).